# Enumerating/Count occurrence of an item consecutively

Tags: r, date, filter, count

I have a table which looks like this:

```
subject_id | hadm_id |admittime          |dischtime | admission location

1          | 1000    |2153-09-03 07:15:00|2153-09-08 19:10:00 | EMERGENCY
2          | 1001    |2134-05-10 11:30:00|2134-05-20 13:16:00 | other 1
1          | 1002    |2122-05-14 19:37:00|2122-05-18 15:11:00 | other 2
4          | 1003    |2153-09-03 07:15:00|2153-09-08 19:10:00 | other 3
2          | 1004    |2153-09-03 07:15:00|2153-09-08 19:10:00 | other 4
```

My objective is to filter on those id's that have an admission location of "other 1" "2" "3" or "Emergency",etc in the first instance (i.e. the first time recorded for an id) and emergency in the next incidence. These are hospital data. Hence, I need to filter with respect on the admission and/or dischtime.

As an example, I want to have the data of a patient who went to the hospital on 21.08.2016. On 31.08.2016 he came to the hospital again, this time it was an emergency. (If it was not an emergency, I would not want to have this id in my final table).

Lastly, if another constraint could be implemented, it would be even better: the time between the first and second or second and third visit needs to be less than 30 days.

The below table is how I imagine the output. I.e. one column showing the enumeration of the hospital visit. In another column (significant?), whether there are 30 or less days between the visits. Also, note, that the second visit **must** be "Emergency".

```
subject_id | hadm_id |admittime          |dischtime | admission location| count of hospital visit | significant?

1          | 1000    |2140-05-03 07:15:00|2153-09-08 19:10:00 | other 2   |  1  | yes 
1          | 1002    |2140-05-14 19:37:00|2122-05-18 15:11:00 | EMERGENCY |  2  | yes
2          | 1001    |2134-05-10 11:30:00|2134-05-20 13:16:00 | other 1   |  1  | no
2          | 1004    |2153-09-03 07:15:00|2153-09-08 19:10:00 | other 4   |  2  | yes
2          | 1003    |2153-09-10 20:15:00|2153-09-08 19:10:00 | EMERGENCY |  3  | yes
```

Comment: there might have been a problem occurring during your time conversion...

Comment: the time is on purpose in the future (because it is confidential information it has been shifted by an unknown number of years for each id. but it is not really affecting what needs to be done.)

Comment: May you use dates from your sample datas in your explanation ? and maybe craft a sample output manually so we can get the logic behind. I still struggle to understand what you're after.

Comment: sure, let me edit my post. the dates are from the original file, though they have been edited prior to giving me the data set.